# Issue connecting to SQL Express

Tags: azure, sql-server-express

I have two visual studio 2010 projects that I am running locally. One is a cloud project and connects to azure table (development) storage in addition to a local SQL Express, the other is not a cloud project. Both projects attempt to connect to a local SQL Express database via similar code generated through an xsd as well as directly in an aspx via a databound grid. The non-cloud project connects fine, but the cloud project fails with the common error:

"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users...mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Both projects use the same connection string in a Web.config file:

```
    <add name="WorkoutLogConnectionString1"
  connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\...mdf;
  Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In VS2010 server explorer from the cloud project I can connect to the express database just fine, but when the project runs, it fails to connect. The cloud project also connects to a SQL Azure remote cloud database via another connection string in Web.config and that connection works fine.

I saw the MS support article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980 and thought that maybe the projects were originally created with different versions of VS and that maybe causing my issues, so I made the suggested IIS changes to the ASP.net 4.0 application pools, but to no avail.

Since the SQL Express connection string works in one project and not in the other I am stumped. Are there some other configuration elements or something related to the failing project being a cloud project that I should be looking at?

Comment: Connection string did not show up: <add name="WorkoutLogConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\...mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: I made the connection string show up. In order to highlight code samples (especially samples that might be interpreted as HTML) use the code button `{}` on the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Are you tyring to run both the project simultaneously (at the same time - multiple startup projects). If so, it is indeed common issue with SQL Express. Often happens also when you have opened the database in your VS Server Explorer. If you have multiple applications accessing the same database, I suggest that you manually attach the database in your SQL Server Express. You can do by:

1. open SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio), connecting to your local SQL Express instance.
2. Navigate to Databases branch
3. Right click -> Attach Database
4. Browse to your mdf file
5. Done!

Now change your connection to the one suggested by Aaron. Generally I advice to now use the AttachDbFilename and UserInstance, but instead attach the database directly and use it as with a regular stand-alone instance of SQL Server. Saves lots of headaches.

Comment: Thanks! I struggled a little bit to get SSMS to find the mdf file (it couldn't navigate my whole directory tree), but I moved the file to my SQL Server DATA directory and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you attached your database to an actual SQL Server Express instance? If so, remove all that `AttachDbFilename` and `User Instance` nonsense. To keep things simple and consistent you could probably use SQL Authenication locally. So you should just have something like:

```
<add name="WorkoutLogConnectionString1"
  connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;
  User ID=SQLAuthUsername;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: This feels like a dumb question, but what would the User ID and Password be? I know what they are for my SQL Azure account, but when I connect to the local DB SSMS show PCName\User with no password. When I tried those, the connection fails.

Comment: If you created a local SQL user name and password, you would use that. Otherwise you should keep just the `Integrated Security = True` part in place of the User ID and Password parts I put above. I was only suggesting SQL auth to keep it consistent with Azure, so if you wanted you *could* create a SQL username and password with sufficient privileges for your app. You could even make it match your Azure account so that only the server name would need to change.

Comment: Thanks. I have a bizarre mix of SQL Server 2008 R2 while still using some SQL Express and so had to specify the connection string Data Source as "(local)".

Comment: Ok, yes, if you have multiple named instances and you are trying to connect to the default instance, you need o use `(local)` or `.` or `SERVERNAME` or `ip.ad.dr.ess`...